# How can I turn on opening a link in another app again?

Tags: ios

I'm using iOS 9.2 and I once accidentally tapped “don't allow” or something similar when WhatsApp was opening a link for Citymapper. It used to launch the Citymapper app, but now it goes to the less useful web interface.

I've looked through all the settings but I can't find any record of this preference to reset the permission.

Metadata on page:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="citymapper://directions?endcoord=51.56819%2C-0.086512&region_id=uk-london" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="469463298" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Citymapper" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.citymapper.app.release" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Citymapper" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="citymapper://directions?endcoord=51.56819%2C-0.086512&region_id=uk-london" />
```

Comment: You probably should be able to uninstall whatsapp, and then reinstall it to fix your issue. But, this is a bit extreme, and there is most likely a better solution out there.

Comment: I tried this, didn't seem to reset anything. Links to citymapper still open in web.

Comment: If you would like more attention to this question (since I think it is a good one), I would suggest starting a bounty.

Comment: I've tested your issue and I cant replicate it. I installed CityMapper and Whatsapp and tried to load a `citymapper://` url from Whatsapp. I pressed Cancel on the popup asking for permission to open the Citymapper App and nothing happened. Then I pressed the link again and the same popup appeared. I would suggest updating to the latest iOS version and the latest version of both apps.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling the citymapper app?

Comment: Yes, I have reinstalled both apps

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, when the web interface pops up in Safari, there should be a banner across the top of the page that essentially says, "Hey, you could view this info in the app instead!" If you tap *OPEN* on that banner, it's supposed to re-establish the universal linking to the app instead of the website. Here it is in Apple's words:

> When a user taps a universal link that [an app] handle[s], iOS also examines the user’s recent choices to determine whether to open [the] app or [the] website. For example, a user who has tapped a universal link to open [the] app can later choose to open [the] website in Safari by tapping a breadcrumb button in the status bar. After the user makes this choice, iOS continues to open [the] website in Safari until the user chooses to open [the] app by tapping OPEN in the Smart App Banner on the webpage.

Source: [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) in Apple's App Search Programming Guide

Comment: Good answer, but the link appears not to be a universal link, just a web link that is then triggering the citymapper app opening like this one: https://citymapper.com/eta/Tfkagpb. The page contains this metadata I've added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try long pressing the link in what's app. you should then get a choice to open in the app or in safari.